# How to get Mocha to execute unit tests in multiple subfolders in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm integrating tests into my Node server and am having some trouble with unit testing. When I run `npm test` in my root directory, Mocha automatically runs all tests inside of my `test` folder. However, the unit tests which are dispersed throughout the project do not run. How can I ensure that Mocha automatically runs them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could modify the `npm test` command to `find` your test files and run `mocha` against them.

Assuming a directory structure like:

```
project/
  src/
    test/
        main-tests.test.js
    things/
        test/
          thing.test.js
    more_things/
      more-things.test.js
```

You would change your `package.json` like this:

```
scripts: {
  ...
  "test": "mocha $(find . -name '*.test.js')"
  ...
}
```

There are probably other ways to do this, like specifying the expected glob patterns of the locations of your test files.

Both of these methods require a plain pattern to the names of your test files.

Comment: This helped but found another issue, Cannot find the "tap' module.
I found this is a better way. https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3092

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you would want to have your tests "dispersed throughout the project". I think you would be much better off keeping all of them in a dedicated test folder. You can mirror the folder structure of your `src` folder, if your concern is that you want to easily find the test for a specific source file. Example:

```
project/
├── src/
│   ├── one/
│   │   └── foo.js
│   └── two/
│       └── bar.js
└── test/
    ├── one/
    │   └── foo.test.js
    └── two/
        └── bar.test.js
```

Regardless of whether you decide to reorganise your project, the way to get mocha to execute all test files recursively is with the following:

```
scripts: {
  "test": "mocha \"./**/*.test.js\""
}
```

You can replace the `.` with `test` or `src` (or any other folder) if you don't want to search the whole project folder.

You can read more about it here: [How do I get mocha to execute tests in all subfolders recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812801/how-do-i-get-mocha-to-execute-tests-in-all-subfolders-recursively)

Comment: I like this setup. How do you test methods in `src` folder from `test`? You must import them like `../src/myscript.mjs`?