# How do I get mocha to execute tests in all subfolders recursively?

Tags: javascript, bash, mocha.js, filepattern

I have my tests grouped in folders, like this:

```
test/
├── unit/
├── integration/
└── acceptance/
```

In each of the above folders, there are a number of test files (e.g. `test.js`)

I execute my different test suites with the following commands:

```
mocha test/unit/**/*.js
mocha test/integration/**/*.js
mocha test/acceptance/**/*.js
```

I recently decided to add a subfolder to `test/unit`, to organise things a bit:

```
test/
└── unit/
    ├── subfolder/
    │   └── new.test.js
    ├── foo.test.js
    └── bar.test.js
```

But now `mocha` is only executing the tests in `new.test.js`.

I thought `/**/*.js` meant that it would recursively look in all folders for `.js` files, but that's not the behaviour I'm seeing. Is this a bug or a misunderstanding on my part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By wrapping those exact same patterns in quotes, `mocha` will be resolving the patterns, rather than `bash`:

```
"scripts": {
  "test:unit": "mocha \"test/unit/**/*.js\""
}
```

Luckily, `mocha` resolves the pattern as expected and will recursively find all `.js` files in `test/unit`, including any level of subfolders.

**TL;DR** There's no need to read any further, unless you are trying to do something similar with something other than `mocha`. The below is just how far I got with `bash`'s file pattern matching:

Without the quotes, I wasn't able to make it work for more than two levels at the time:

```
mocha test/unit/**
```

The above matches all files in `test/unit` and the first level of subfolders, but this will match any file and not just `.js`

```
mocha test/unit/{,**/}*.js
```

Now we are matching only `.js` files, but still only in `test/unit` and the first level of subfolders.